# PowerShell Return Type

Tags: powershell, casting, wmi

I am creating a test application to get system information.

When I run this command

```
[int] $cdCodeIntTest = Get-WmiObject win32_cdromdrive | select ConfigManagerErrorCode
```

According to the powershell program:
it returns a "Selected.System.Management.ManagementObject", but the online documentation says that the type is a [uint32] (unsigned 32 bit integer).

How do I typecast the error code to an integer or hex value so that I can switch on the value at a later point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to expand the property to get just the value, otherwise you get back an object with one property (ConfigManagerErrorCode):

```
Get-WmiObject win32_cdromdrive | select -expand ConfigManagerErrorCode
```

Comment: Thanks. Great answer, you solved the problem and pointed me in the right direction to learn more. Thanks!